# Отправка файла на сервер через http, и отображение прогресса

Tags: python, http

Думаю как сделать выгрузку файла через http, и так, чтобы отображался прогресс хода отправки.

Подскажите вариант решения, или в какую сторону копать, хотя бы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно ли я понял, что файл нужно отправлять прямо из скрипта? Если так, то есть библиотека requests, а пример кода уже пробегал на SO:
[Send file using POST from a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script)
Однако, отображать прогресс при этом вряд ли получится - для этого нужно будет бить файл на блоки и создавать класс:
[Progress of Python requests post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14953090/8030503), и работать уже с chunks
Что касается отображения самого прогресса, то тут можно сделать что-то типа такого (делал впопыхах для какого-то проекта, но разобраться можно:

```
import time #only to make delay between operations for demonstration purposes

class pBar():
    def __init__ (self, vmax, length=25, bchar=u"\u25A0"):
        self.vmax = vmax            #vmax - total number of items to iterate
        self.bchar = bchar          #symbol to use as bar mark
        self.length = length        #lenght - bar length in characters
        self.val = 0
        self.cur = 0

    def incr (self):
        self.val += 1
        self.cur = int((self.val/self.vmax)*self.length)
        print('[' + self.bchar*self.cur + ' '*(self.length-self.cur) + ']' + ' '*(4-len(str(int(self.val*100/self.vmax)))) + str(int(self.val*100/self.vmax)), end='%\r')
        if self.val == self.vmax :
            print('\n') # to make output less messy

mybar = pBar(56)
#demo:
i = 0
while i < 56 :
    mybar.incr()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    i += 1
```